Homotopy equivalence between $ S^1 $ and a space of quadratic equations with distinct real roots
Let $X = \{(a, b, c) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid b^2 > 4ac\}$. I am trying to prove that $X$ has the homotopy type of $S^1$.
This problem arises from an exercise in a topology textbook, where I am supposed to use deformation retracts or homotopy equivalence to justify this result. I understand that $S^1$ represents a circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and $X$ can be seen as the set of coefficients of quadratic equations with distinct real roots.
I have tried to:

Find a subset $Y \subseteq X$ homeomorphic to $S^1$,
Construct a deformation retract of $X$ onto $Y$.

However, I am struggling to:

Identify $Y$ explicitly,
Prove that $Y$ is a deformation retract of $X$.

Could someone provide hints or guidance on how to approach this problem, or clarify the geometric intuition behind $X$ and its relationship to $S^1$?

I would first recommend trying to understand exactly what $X$ looks like - drawing solutions for $b^2>4ac$ in the $a,b$-plane for various values of $c$ (say, $c=-1,0,1$) was helpful for me. This should help identify a useful deformation retract; I'd personally go with projection onto the $b,c$-plane, but it won't be obvious how this works until you can visualise $X$ as a space. The projection should give you something that looks more familiar and is easily corresponded with $S^1$.

Let $P: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be homogeneous and continuous of degree $n$, i.e. $P(\lambda x) = \lambda^n P(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$.
Then
$$r: X_P:=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \, | \, P(x) > 0 \} \to X_P^0 := \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \, | \, P(x) = 1 \}, \, x \mapsto \frac{x}{\sqrt[n]{P(x)}}$$
is a strong deformation retraction because $r(x) = x$ for $P(x) = 1$, i.e. $r \circ \iota = id_{X_P^0}$ with $\iota: X_P^0 \to X_P$ the natural inclusion, and
$$H: X_P \times [0,1] \to X_P, \, (x,t) \mapsto \left(\frac{1-t}{\sqrt[n]{P(x)}} + t\right)x$$
is a homotopy with $H(\cdot, 0) = r$ and $H(\cdot, 1) = id_{X_P}$.
Now let $P(a,b,c):= b^2 - 4ac$ for $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $P$ is homogeneous of degree $2$. Therefore
$$X = X_P \simeq X_P^0 = \{(a,b,c) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \, | \, b^2 - 4ac = 1\}$$ (where $\simeq$ means homotopy equivalent).
So, it is only to show that $X_P^0 \simeq S^1$. Define the matrix $A := \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & -2 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ -2 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.
Then
$$b^2 -4ac = (a,b,c)A\begin{pmatrix}a \\ b \\ c\end{pmatrix}$$
and thus $X_P^0 = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^3 \, | \, x^TAx = 1\}$. $A$ is symmetric so there is an orthogonal matrix $S \in O(3)$ and diagonal matrix $D = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -2 \end{pmatrix}$ with $S^TDS = A$. Hence there is a homeomorphism given by $S$
$$X_0^P \cong SX_P^0 = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^3 \, | \, x^TDx = 1\} = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \, | \, x^2+2y^2-2z^2 = 1\}$$
Change the variable by homeomorphism $\Phi: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3, (x,y,z) \mapsto (x,\sqrt{2}y, \sqrt{2}z)$ and get
$$SX_P^0 \cong \Phi(SX_P^0) = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \, | \, x^2+y^2-z^2 = 1\}$$
$H_1 := \Phi(SX_P^0)$ is the one-sheet hyperboloid (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperboloid). It strongly deformation retracts onto the circle $S^1$ by
$$R: H_1 \to S^1, \, (x,y,z) \mapsto (x,y)$$
(proof left as an easy exercise).
All in all,
$$X = X_P \simeq X_P^0 \cong \Phi(SX_P^0) = H_1 \simeq S^1$$
and all of this by strong deformation retracts.

good. On the previous incarnation of the question, I suggested he do the problem for $x^2 + y^2 > z^2$  and the hyperboloid $x^2 + y^2 = 1 + z^2.$  So he deleted the question
